# View blob (image, pdf, or doc) in web app

Tags: html, angular, image, pdf, doc

I'm trying to view image, pdf or doc files in an angular web app.

ts code:

```
this.fileService.getFile(fileId).subscribe(
    result => {
        let blob = new Blob([result[0].data], { type: result[0].type });
        this.FileType = result[0].type;
        this.FileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    },
    error => {}
);
```

HTML:

```
<img    *ngIf="FileType.indexOf('image') != -1" [src]="FileUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'">
<iframe *ngIf="FileType.indexOf('image') == -1" [src]="'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=' + FileUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'" width="100%" height="100px"></iframe>
```

If it's an image than it runs without any problem, but for pdf and doc files I get this error:
  [image: error]

This code was working a few months ago...

As a quick fix, I've added a download button for the files which works:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [href]="FileUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'" download>Download file</a>
```

Any suggestions on how to view pdf or doc files in an angular web app *(other than downloading, or opening in a new tab/window)*?

Comment: Are you sure that you have those files on your google drive?

Comment: I get them from a blob storage.

Comment: `[src]="'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=' + FileUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'"` shouldn't you switch this to  `[src]="FileUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'"` then?

Comment: This works in most browsers (except IE), but only for PDFs.

Comment: How does your request look like, what is the URL for that iframe src?

Comment: FileUrl = 'blob:http://siteAddress.com/file-Id-number'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195187/discussion-between-dusan-radovanovic-and-barna-tekse).